# Why can't TeamCity collect changes when submodule changes?

Tags: git, teamcity

*Please see the bottom of the text for latest update:*

I have a git repo with a submodule.  The build works locally but when I try it in TeamCity (version Professional 2019.1.3 (build 66439)) I get the error message:

> Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS
> repository '"SubModuleTest_ab" {instance id=2991, parent internal
> id=190, parent id=MegaTester_SubModuleTestAb, description: "the url"}'
> 'git fetch' command failed (repository dir: /system/caches/git/git-4883F794.git). stderr: url: 422
> Unprocessable Entity exit code: 1, VCS root: "SubModuleTest_ab"
> {instance id=2991, parent internal id=190, parent
> id=MegaTester_SubModuleTestAb, description: "the url"}

This seems to be caused by the submodule being added - the same repo with a branch that does not include the submodule works.

I have looked at other answers about submodules in TeamCity but none of their solutions seemed to work.  I have tried:

- Adding .git to the URL in in the submodules file
- Adding an extra commit to the submodule repo
- Changing the authentication from https to ssh (I was pretty sure this was not going to work but I am getting desperate)
- Specifying master as the submodule branch rather than leaving it
  default

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Additional:

I have kept playing back and forth and what seems to happen is that I have a repo with a submodule.  This builds normally.

**If I change the submodule code then TeamCity fails to fetch the changes.  Nothing else has changed.**  This can sometimes be fixed by changing the credentials of the user.  Presumably this wipes a cache or something.

The branch clean policy is set to always and checkout policy is set to delete all files each build.

The error message that is logged is still:

*'git fetch' command failed (repository dir: /system/caches/git/git-4883F794.git*

Any ideas?

Comment: The 422 error suggests that the URL is wrong. See https://httpstatuses.com/422 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422 (the latter is more precise and has a link to the WebDAV extensions probably being used here, but it ends up being the same thing).

Comment: I have confirmed that the URL is correct.  The TeamCity project can see some GitLab repos but not the latest 2 I made.  I cannot see any differences which would cause this though

Comment: That points the error-finger towards your HTTPS server, then. Investigate it; see why it's producing 422 errors.

Comment: But other projects from the same server connect fine..  How do I trouble shoot this?

Comment: Can you get logs from the web server? Failing that (or in addition), can you make network packet traces (tcpdump / wireshark) of the conversations from client to server?

Comment: @torek, , it looks like it is not to do with network, changing a submodule's code stops the fetch operation from working.  Nothing else changed.  I can repeat it at will now.

Comment: Repeatable is good. Now you can collect logs from the server, and examine both a success case and a failure case and see why the server rejects the failure case.

Comment: After all of that I am back to the error message I originally started with.  The fail log file has it and the success log file does not ... ARGHGARAGAGAHFH

Comment: You are "checking out on server", right ? If so, have you tried to "checkout on agent" ? It seems like Teamcity is optimized for agent checkout, so it might help.

Comment: Thanks, however we are checking out on the agent side :-(